# Eclipse never asks me to install android, SDK manager says no directory set

Tags: android, sdk, android-virtual-device

I only partially installed AVD manager

can we ask troubleshooting questions here? I just see a lot of Android questions

Anyway my predicament - even after trying to reinstall eclipse, uninstall plugins - is that the Android plugins never prompt me to download the actual SDK

I'm stuck, if I click on anything related to Android, it says the SDK folder doesn't exist. Which I already know because I cancelled the download the first time it asked me (I changed my mind about the location, anyway this opened up a can of worms)

How else can I get the SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download SDK on your own (from android page). Save it on computer. Then in Eclipse: Window->Preferences->Android and you will see "SDK Location": Just browse to your downloaded SDK.

You can also just follow this link [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), if you go step by step there shouldnt be any problems

Answer (score 0):

You can download it from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) or from your searching at your Eclipse Market.

After the download you must set the *SDK Location* at the Preferences (Window > Preferences > Android).

Answer (score 0):

First of all download the Android SDK & install it in your PC then you should set a path for that SDK from Eclipse

Then in Eclipse: Window->Preferences->Android and you will see "SDK Location": Just browse to your downloaded SDK.